# Создание экземпляра внутреннего класса

Tags: java

Вопрос по синтаксису Java. Я уже относительно давно пишу на этом языке. Но недавно понял, что не знаю, как создать экземпляр внутреннего класса извне, если этот класс нестатический. Например, у меня есть класс:

```
class Outer {
   Outer() {
   }

   ...

   class Inner {
     Inner() {
     }

     ...

   }    
}
```

Как из внешнего класса создать экземпляр класса `Inner`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Как известно, нестатичный внутренний класс должен быть связан с объектом класса-родителя.
Если у вас есть такой объект, конструктор внутреннего класса вызывается следующим образом.

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
```

Comment: Совершенно верно, если не создан Outer, то нестатичный Inner создать невозможно

Comment: А это не будет работать?
   Innter inner = new Outer.Inner();

Comment: @AlexAndR, нет, только если класс Inner статичный.

Comment: IMHO это становится очевидным, если спросить себя:

к каким переменным, которые находятся в  Outer сможет обращаться созданный экземпляр Inner ? 

Если Outer не создавался, то этих переменных попросту **нет**.

Comment: Ну да, подумал повнимательней, всё равно что вопрос:

"Как обратиться к нестатичному полю не создавая класса"

получается...

Answer (score 5):

Рабочий вариант, проверено в коде:

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
```

Либо в одну строку создаем 2 объекта:

```
Outer.Inner inner = new Outer().new Inner();
```

---

PS Вариант предложенный [@СиницынАртём](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/99940/217579) у меня выдает ошибку!
<sub>Ошибка исправлена, см. историю правок (*прим. ред.*).</sub>